# Unknown type "Upload" - Apollo Server Express with graphql-upload Node 14

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

I am working with GraphQL and is facing an issue with File Upload. My Node version is v14.16.0

I am getting error as below

> Error: Unknown type "Upload". Did you mean "Float"?

Below are the package version installed

Package versions

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.23.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "consola": "^2.15.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql-upload": "^11.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  }
```

Below is my server setup done with apollo-server-express and graphql-upload package

```
import express from "express";
import consola from "consola";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
const { error, success } = consola;
import { PORT } from "./config/index.js";
import { typeDefs, resolvers } from "./graphql/index.js";
import * as AppModels from "./models/index.js";
import compression from "compression";
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from "graphql-upload";
//Initialize the app
const app = express();
app.use(compression());
app.use(
  graphqlUploadExpress({
    maxFileSize: 30000000,
    maxFiles: 20,
  })
);

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  uploads: false,
  context: {
    ...AppModels,
  },
});
app.use(express.static("public"));

server.applyMiddleware({ app });
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  success({
    badge: true,
    message: `Server started at ${PORT}`,
  });
});
```

Here are my type definition for imageUpload Mutation

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";
export default gql`
  extend type Mutation {
    imageUploader(file: Upload!): String!
  }
`;
```

My resolver looks like this

```
import { createWriteStream } from "fs";
import { parse, join } from "path";
import { URL } from "../../config/index.js";
export default {
  Mutation: {
    imageUploader: async (_, { file }) => {
      let { filename, createReadStream } = await file;
      let stream = createReadStream();
      let { name, ext } = parse(filename);
      name = name.replace(/([^a-z0-9 ]+)/gi, "-").replace(" ", "_");
      let serverFile = `D:/${name}${ext}`;
      let writeStream = await createWriteStream(serverFile);
      await stream.pipe(writeStream);
      //serverFile = `${URL}/${serverFile.split("uploads")[1]}`;
      return serverFile;
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Well this is for anybody who faces the situation

As we are using the graphl-upload package so we need to define the custom scalar in typedef and assign the Upload type in resolver.

So now my typedef looks like this. Notice the code **scalar Upload**

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";
export default gql`
  scalar Upload
  extend type Mutation {
    imageUploader(file: Upload!): String!
  }
`;
```

After typedef changes we need to define a resolver for that scalar. So now the resolver looks like this

```
import { createWriteStream } from "fs";
import { GraphQLUpload } from "graphql-upload";
import { parse, join } from "path";
import { URL } from "../../config/index.js";
export default {
  Upload: GraphQLUpload,
  Mutation: {
    imageUploader: async (_, { file }) => {
      let { filename, createReadStream } = await file;
      let stream = createReadStream();
      let { name, ext } = parse(filename);
      name = name.replace(/([^a-z0-9 ]+)/gi, "-").replace(" ", "_");
      let serverFile = `D:/${name}${ext}`;
      let writeStream = await createWriteStream(serverFile);
      await stream.pipe(writeStream);
      //serverFile = `${URL}/${serverFile.split("uploads")[1]}`;
      return serverFile;
    },
  },
};
```

Above code helped me in getting pass that issue.

Comment: i am not gettting createReadStream  in file. I am getting filename

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **NODE 14**

```
import {ApolloServer} from "apollo-server-express";
...
// If you want to see uploaded images, then you need to add these commands and, 
// create a folder to upload images name like 'uploads'

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, './uploads')));
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 1000000000, maxFiles: 10 }));
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

const server = new ApolloServer({
uploads: false,   // --------- use this
typeDefs,
resolvers,
plugins: [IN_PROD ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground() : 
ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled(),
    ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({httpServer})],
context: {
    ...AppModels
  }
});
```

after that, in **typeDefs**,

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";

export default gql`
  scalar Upload // ---- use this


extend type Mutation {
    imageUploader(file: Upload!): String!
   }
`;
```

after that, In **resolvers**

```
import {parse, join} from 'path';
import {createWriteStream} from 'fs';
import {URL} from "../../../config";
import {GraphQLUpload} from "graphql-upload";

export default {
   Upload: GraphQLUpload, // ----- use this

Query: {
    info: () => "Hello i am image resolver methods."
 },
Mutation: {
    imageUploader: async (_, {file}) => {
        try {
            let {
                filename,
                createReadStream
            } = await file;
            let stream = createReadStream();

            let {
                ext,
                name
            } = parse(filename);

            name = name.replace(/([^a-z0-9 ]+)/gi, '-').replace(' ', '_');

            let serverFile = join(__dirname, 
            `../../../uploads/${name}-${Date.now()}${ext}`);

            let writeStream = await createWriteStream(serverFile);
            await stream.pipe(writeStream);

            let lastPath = serverFile.split('uploads')[1];
            lastPath = lastPath.replace('\\', '/');
            serverFile = `${URL}${lastPath}`;

            return serverFile;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR UPLOAD A IMAGE", e);
            throw e;
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

[Github](https://github.com/sachinthadilshandisanayaka/Apollo-curd-server-nodeJS.git) link